# Setting the spaces in a beamer mini frame

Tags: beamer, spacing, mini-frames

I am writing a custom beamer template and I'd like to use mini frames for the navigation in it, however I'd like to avoid having the spacing that they have by default:

[image]

the problem here is that beamer sets the space among each section name (thus considering their length) to be the same!, whereas the correct way to do that would be to set equally spaced column first and then write the names starting from each column (names would have different length spaces between them, but they would align to a grid).

An even further step would be the possibility to set the grid in advance (specifying the number of columns) and having the names starting from one of those (going on a newline if they are more than the columns). I know this would be too much maybe (I've never seen a latex layout based on a grid), so getting the first part of the question answered is fine : )

Comment: Close voters: how is this *primarily opinion based*? It's not a question of what is correct. It's not really unclear either, though a minimal example would be nice, of course.